# terraform init is taking forever in the "initializing modules" stage. How to fix it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, terraform, terraform-modules

I am working with terraform and we use modules for everything. So, tf init is a command that I use very frequently. Since a couple days, my init stopped running as ususal. It is taking way too long for some reason. for something that used to complete in 1 min, is now taking anywhere from 5 to 20 mins.

I tried to search a similar issue but failed. to get some context of what is happening in the background, I turned on the tf logs by setting env variable `TF_LOG` to `TRACE`.
Below is the output. Please see the time stamp on line #16 it takes **8 mins** to fetch the module from git repo.

I tried cloning the repo to a new workspace and it was done instantly without any issue.. so I am thinking there is no issue with git. I am clueless on what seems to be causing this lag.

```
➜  rds git:(banch-name) ✗ tfI -reconfigure
2023/04/27 09:22:43 [INFO] Terraform version: 0.11.15  
2023/04/27 09:22:43 [INFO] Go runtime version: go1.12.13
2023/04/27 09:22:43 [INFO] CLI args: []string{"/Users/.terraform.versions/terraform_0.11.15", "init", "-reconfigure"}
2023/04/27 09:22:43 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /Users/.terraformrc
2023/04/27 09:22:43 Loading CLI configuration from /Users/.terraformrc
2023/04/27 09:22:43 [INFO] CLI command args: []string{"init", "-reconfigure"}
2023/04/27 09:22:43 [DEBUG] command: loading backend config file: /Users/Workspaces/Workspace1/terraform-automation/rds
Initializing modules...
2023/04/27 09:22:43 [TRACE] module source: "git@github.com:/terraform-modules//60_rds/mysql/"
- module.rds
2023/04/27 09:22:43 [TRACE] detected module source "git::ssh://git@github.com/terraform-modules"
2023/04/27 09:22:43 [DEBUG] fetching module from git::ssh://git@github.com/terraform-modules
2023/04/27 09:22:43 [DEBUG] fetching "git::ssh://git@github.com/terraform-modules" with key "1.rds;git@github.com:/terraform-modules//60_rds/mysql/"
  Getting source "git@github.com:/terraform-modules//60_rds/mysql/"
2023/04/27 09:22:46 [ERR] Checkpoint error: Get https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/terraform?arch=amd64&os=darwin&-b750-ccd3-a3ed-50ab4f8585e3&version=0.11.15: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2023/04/27 09:30:45 [DEBUG] found "git::ssh://git@github.com/terraform-modules" in ".terraform/modules/084341d9911db88e67ac648f8085f1e4": true
2023/04/27 09:30:45 [TRACE] "git::ssh://git@github.com/terraform-modules" stored in ".terraform/modules/084341d9911db88e67ac648f8085f1e4"

Initializing the backend...
2023/04/27 09:30:45 [DEBUG] command: no data state file found for backend config
2023/04/27 09:30:45 [DEBUG] New state was assigned lineage "75e116b8-3a16-58f4-f012-0fe3ac026460"
2023/04/27 09:30:45 [INFO] Setting AWS metadata API timeout to 100ms
2023/04/27 09:30:46 [INFO] Ignoring AWS metadata API endpoint at default location as it doesn't return any instance-id
2023/04/27 09:30:46 [INFO] AWS Auth using Profile: "profile"
2023/04/27 09:30:46 [DEBUG] Trying to get account information via sts:GetCallerIdentity
2023/04/27 09:30:46 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request sts/AssumeRole Details: ""
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "."
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/Users/.terraform.versions"
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] checking for provider in ".terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64"
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-aws_v4.64.0_x5"
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-random_v3.5.1_x5"
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-template_v2.2.0_x4"
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "random", "3.5.1", "/Users/Workspaces/Workspace1/terraform-automation/rds/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-random_v3.5.1_x5"
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "template", "2.2.0", "/Users/Workspaces/Workspace1/terraform-automation/rds/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-template_v2.2.0_x4"
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "aws", "4.64.0", "/Users/Workspaces/Workspace1/terraform-automation/rds/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v4.64.0_x5"
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/Users/.terraform.versions"
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in ".terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64"
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] New state was assigned lineage "7bdcc4ee-373a-698e-b604-c77ef150e5c7"
2023/04/27 09:30:54 [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "7bdcc4ee-373a-698e-b604-c77ef150e5c7"



Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.


2023/04/27 09:30:54 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request s3/ListObjects Details:
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [INFO] command: backend initialized: *s3.Backend
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "."
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/Users/.terraform.versions"
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] checking for provider in ".terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64"
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-aws_v4.64.0_x5"
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-random_v3.5.1_x5"
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-template_v2.2.0_x4"
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "random", "3.5.1", "/Users/Workspaces/Workspace1/terraform-automation/rds/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-random_v3.5.1_x5"
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "template", "2.2.0", "/Users/Workspaces/Workspace1/terraform-automation/rds/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-template_v2.2.0_x4"
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "aws", "4.64.0", "/Users/Workspaces/Workspace1/terraform-automation/rds/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v4.64.0_x5"
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/Users/.terraform.versions"
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in ".terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64"
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [INFO] command: backend *s3.Backend is not enhanced, wrapping in local
2023/04/27 09:30:58 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request s3/ListObjects Details:
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] {"Item":{"Digest":{"S":"a66646da58408d01135b9b515823cc60"},"LockID":{"S":"-rds/terraform.tfstate-md5"}}}
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "0c570823-a5ba-c934-5928-4ea770966cab"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "0c570823-a5ba-c934-5928-4ea770966cab"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [TRACE] module source: "git@github.com:/terraform-modules//60_rds/mysql/"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "."
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/Users/.terraform.versions"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] checking for provider in ".terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-aws_v4.64.0_x5"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-random_v3.5.1_x5"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-template_v2.2.0_x4"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "aws", "4.64.0", "/Users/Workspaces/Workspace1/terraform-automation/rds/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v4.64.0_x5"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "random", "3.5.1", "/Users/Workspaces/Workspace1/terraform-automation/rds/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-random_v3.5.1_x5"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "template", "2.2.0", "/Users/Workspaces/Workspace1/terraform-automation/rds/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-template_v2.2.0_x4"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] plugin requirements: "aws"=""
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] plugin requirements: "random"=""
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] plugin requirements: "template"=""
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "."

2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/Users/.terraform.versions"
Initializing provider plugins...
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] checking for provider in ".terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-aws_v4.64.0_x5"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-random_v3.5.1_x5"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-template_v2.2.0_x4"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "random", "3.5.1", "/Users/Workspaces/Workspace1/terraform-automation/rds/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-random_v3.5.1_x5"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "template", "2.2.0", "/Users/Workspaces/Workspace1/terraform-automation/rds/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-template_v2.2.0_x4"
2023/04/27 09:31:11 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "aws", "4.64.0", "/Users/Workspaces/Workspace1/terraform-automation/rds/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v4.64.0_x5"
2023/04/27 09:31:12 [DEBUG] checking for provider in ".terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64"
2023/04/27 09:31:12 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-aws_v4.64.0_x5"
2023/04/27 09:31:12 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-random_v3.5.1_x5"
2023/04/27 09:31:12 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-template_v2.2.0_x4"

The following providers do not have any version constraints in configuration,
2023/04/27 09:31:12 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
so the latest version was installed.

To prevent automatic upgrades to new major versions that may contain breaking
changes, it is recommended to add version = "..." constraints to the
corresponding provider blocks in configuration, with the constraint strings
suggested below.

* provider.aws: version = "~> 4.64"
* provider.random: version = "~> 3.5"
* provider.template: version = "~> 2.2"

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
```

More info:

- There is a checkpoint error for some reason.. in my other attempts
  where I don't have this error, I still have the same time delay.
- Using latest versions of tf doesn't help with this lag/delay.